# Pandas has two dataframes, want the average of the divisions between each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```py
dataA = [["A1", "t1", 5], ["A1", "t2", 8], ["A1", "t3", 7],
    ["A1","t4", 4], ["A1", "t5", 2], ["A1", "t6", 2],
    ["A2", "t1", 15], ["A2", "t2", 6], ["A2", "t3", 1], 
    ["A2", "t4", 11], ["A2", "t5", 12], ["A2", "t6", 7], 
    ["A3", "t1", 12], ["A3", "t2", 8], ["A3", "t3", 3], 
    ["A3", "t4", 7], ["A3", "t5", 15], ["A3", "t6", 14]]

dataB = [["B1", "t1", 2], ["B1", "t2", 9], ["B1", "t3", 17],
    ["B1","t4", 14], ["B1", "t5", 32], ["B1", "t6", 3],
    ["B2", "t1", 44], ["B2", "t2", 36], ["B2", "t3", 51], 
    ["B2", "t4", 81], ["B2", "t5", 82]]

data1 = pd.DataFrame(data = dataA, columns=["An", "colA", "Val"])

data2 = pd.DataFrame(data = dataB, columns=["Bm", "colA", "Val"])
```

How to get  this result:

```
 GroupA | GroupB| result | 
 ---------------------------
| A1    | B1    | val_11 | 
 --------------------------
| A1    | B2    | val_12 | 
 --------------------------
| A2    | B1    | val_21 | 
 --------------------------
| A2    | B2    | val_22 | 
 --------------------------
| A3    | B1    | val_31 |
 --------------------------
| A3    | B2    | val_32 |

...........................

| An    | Bm    | val_nm  |
```

The way calculate val_nm  as follows: val_11 is equal to the column mean value of the column value of A1 divided by the column value of B1,
Note that the column A1 divided by the column B1, the corresponding number is divided by the result, **if it is greater than 1, take the reciprocal**, and then find the average of the result
So whether A1 is divided by B1 or B1 is divided by A1, the result value must be the same.

In order to calculate val, it may be necessary to define a function, val is greater than 0, there will be no division by 0

I take val_11  as example

A1[5,8,7,4,2,2]   B1[2,9,17,14,32,3]

val_11 =avg (A1/B1) =avg(**5/2 take 2/5** + 8/9 +7/17 + 4/15 +2/32 +2/3)

= 0.4525

so no matter  A1/B1 or B1/A1,  result will be the same

please help  me caculate result

Comment: Specifically, what are asking for help with? Merging the data frames? Implementing the arithmetic? Specifying the logic? We don't just "write the code" for you here. You need to have a specific question about programming problem and some past efforts to show

Comment: sorry i didn't make it clearly ，i wrtie some thing wrong， i have modified。i want to get result  table or dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the straight definition of what you want to calculate

- shape data frames first,  data is key / value pairs, create tables using `pivot()`
- do a Cartesian product between the two tables `merge()` on a synthetic column **foo**
- complete calculation you specified
- filter down columns to get to your required output

```
def meanofdiv(dfa):
    a = dfa.loc[:,[c for c in dfa.columns if "_A" in c]].values 
    b = dfa.loc[:,[c for c in dfa.columns if "_B" in c]].values
    return np.where((a/b)>1, b/a, a/b).mean(axis=1)

# pivot key/val pair data to tables
# caretesian product of tables
# simple calculation of columns from A and a column from B
dfr = pd.merge(
    data1.pivot(index="An", columns="colA", values="Val").reset_index().assign(foo=1),
    data2.pivot(index="Bm", columns="colA", values="Val").reset_index().assign(foo=1),
    on="foo",
    suffixes=("_A","_B")
).assign(resname=lambda dfa: dfa["An"]+dfa["Bm"],
        res=meanofdiv)

dfr.loc[:,["An","Bm","res"]]
```

|  | An | Bm | res |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A1 | B1 | 0.452589 |
| 1 | A1 | B2 | 0.202259 |
| 2 | A2 | B1 | 0.408018 |
| 3 | A2 | B2 | 0.206316 |
| 4 | A3 | B1 | 0.40251 |
| 5 | A3 | B2 | 0.172901 |

#### ragged data sets

- this deals with A and B sets being different lengths and stopping calc at last B observation
- changed to be row by row `apply(axis=1)`
- modify arrays to be same size by looking at **NaN** in B

```
def meanofdiv(dfa):
    dfa = dfa.to_frame().T
    a = dfa.loc[:,[c for c in dfa.columns if "_A" in c]].astype(float).values[0] 
    b = dfa.loc[:,[c for c in dfa.columns if "_B" in c]].astype(float).values[0]
    a = a[~np.isnan(b)]
    b = b[~np.isnan(b)]
    return np.where((a/b)>1, b/a, a/b).mean()

# pivot key/val pair data to tables
# caretesian product of tables
# simple calculation of columns from A and a column from B
dfr = pd.merge(
    data1.pivot(index="An", columns="colA", values="Val").reset_index().assign(foo=1),
    data2.pivot(index="Bm", columns="colA", values="Val").reset_index().assign(foo=1),
    on="foo",
    suffixes=("_A","_B")
).assign(resname=lambda dfa: dfa["An"]+dfa["Bm"],
        res=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(meanofdiv, axis=1))
```

Comment: sorry,i write wrong about dataB ， I have modified。 and also  I illastrate wrong about caculating res ，and  i also modified

Comment: You also changed the sample data without saying.... have updated answer to do calculation you have now specified.  The approach is not changed at all,  just integrated the calculation now it's defined

Comment: thank you , you soled  my big problem，really thank you！

Comment: one more question,  if A1 B1, is not the same size，like A1 has 6 

number ，but B1 has 5 number， how to  just caculate in front 5 

pair ？    can  we modify function meanofdiv( )  to auto fix 

different  size   caculation？

Comment: there a subtle side effect of `suffixes` param...  if they are not balanced, the suffix is not applied,  hence arrays are same size and extra values are ignored `['An', 't1_A', 't2_A', 't3_A', 't4_A', 't5_A', 't6_A', 't7', 'foo', 'Bm',
       't1_B', 't2_B', 't3_B', 't4_B', 't5_B', 't6_B'],`. see column is called **t7** not **t7_A** so it's not picked out

Comment: is there a  better a way ?  becouse An is certain size，but Bm may has different size，it may be  5 number， maybe 3 number。  what if  we count  size in function meanofdiv（）   and caculate it ？

Comment: I actually think this is a good way.... what is the calc if the sizes are not equal? Bn padded with what? Can you update question with sample data where they are unequal sizes?

Comment: extra values are not ignored，if the sizes are not equal ，and caculation result become NaN， i will  update dataB right now

Comment: ok - that is how the code is written,  but what is the required calc?  it's easy to do a `fillna()` on the arrays,  but you need to define with what

Comment: i update question already,   if  the arrays are not  the same  size，  just caculate The first few numbers ，and  ignore extra values 。and result Shouldn't be  NAN

Comment: I've provided an update - it's straight forward if you really fully define your requirements and really think about your edge cases.

Comment: It's very good and beyond my imagination, thank you very much！really thank you！